# Microsoft graph for "mail merge" feature?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365connectors

We develop an enterprise application that contains data our clients would like to surface in Office 365 for mail merge purposes. Is the Microsoft Graph API appropriate for this purpose? I can't find anything specific to mail merge functionality. If the Graph is not appropriate, is there an alternative API we've missed?

L

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph to send emails and read contact information to populate email templates. Here is a code sample you might find useful:
https://github.com/OfficeGSX/Excel-Add-in-TypeScript-MailMerge

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the link you provided appears to be broken.

Comment: Updated with the correct link: https://github.com/OfficeGSX/Excel-Add-in-TypeScript-MailMerge